# Evaluate the integral $(x-2) e^x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I think this problem can be solved using integration by parts. So I set it up as $u = e^x$ and $du = e^x, dv = (x-2)$ and x = (x^2)/(2)-(2x)

But I don't think I'm getting the right answer. Are my $u$ and $v$ wrong?

Comment: Yes they are. Let $u=x-2$ and $dv=e^x\,dx$.

Comment: I think you are better off setting $dv=e^x$ (so that $v=e^x$ as well) and $u=(x-2)$, so that $du=1$.

Comment: That's what I originally ended up doing. But then we have to use the bounds (5, 2) to get the answer, and I couldn't get the correct answer u = x-2, du - dx, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should flip the two. As a Mnemonic, remember the [LIATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule) rule.
Exponentials should come "last"

\begin{align}
\int(x-2)\exp(x) &= (x-2)\int \exp(x) - \int \left(\frac{d}{dx}(x-2)\right) \cdot\exp(x)\\
&=(x-2)\exp(x)-\exp(x)+C\\
&=(x-3)\exp(x)+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

To integrate function $u(dv)$, the product rule can be stated as:-

$\int u(dv) = uv - \int v(du) $

The trick is to set $u$ and $dv$ such that both $du$ and $v$ are simpler functions, such that you can easily integrate $v(du)$ - the second term.

For our case, setting $u=(x-2)$ and $dv=e^x$, results in $du=1$ and $v=e^x$, so that $v(du)$ is $e^x$, so $\int v(du)dx=\int e^xdx$ is simply $e^x$. So we have

$\int (x-2)e^xdx=(x-2)e^x-\int e^xdx=(x-2)e^x-e^x=xe^x-3e^x$

If, on the other hand, you had set $u=e^x$ and $dv=(x-2)$, $v(du)$ would be $(\frac{x^2}{2}-2x)e^x$, which is far more complicated to integrate, and you would end up with

$\int (x-2)e^xdx=(\frac{x^2}{2}-2x)e^x-\int(\frac{x^2}{2}-2x)e^xdx$

For bounds $[5,2]$

$ \int_5^2(x-2)e^xdx=[(x-2)e^x]_5^2-\int_5^2 e^xdx=-3e^5-e^2+e^5=-2e^5-e^2$

Comment: Alijah Ahmed gives the best answer integration by parts SHOULD ALWAYS BE CONSIDERED first when doing an integration of functions that are multiplied together. Forget the other mumbo jumbo these users are throwing at you when trying to learn basic integration.

Answer (score 2):

> $u = e^x, dv = (x-2)$
>
> Are my $u$ and $v$ wrong?

Yes, they are. *With your selection of $u$ and $v$ the integration becomes more difficult*. To become *easier* it should be the *other way round*, i.e $u=(x-2)$ and $dv=e^x$.

However, I would recomment the following. First split $\int (x-2)e^{x}\,dx$ into two integrals:

\begin{equation*}
I=\int (x-2)e^{x}\,dx=\int xe^{x}\,dx-2\int e^{x}\,dx.
\end{equation*}

Then, since $\int e^{x}\,dx=e^{x}$, we are left with

\begin{equation*}
I=\int xe^{x}\,dx-2e^{x}.
\end{equation*}

The remaining integral $\int xe^{x}dx$ is *easily integrable by parts*, but
you should *differentiate* $x$ and *integrate* $e^{x}$, *not otherwise*, i.e. you should choose $u(x)=x$ and $v^{\prime }(x)=e^{x}$ (or $dv=e^{x}dx$)

\begin{equation*}
\int x\cdot e^{x}\,dx=\int x\cdot e^{x}\,dx=e^{x}x-\int
e^{x}\,dx=e^{x}x-e^{x}+C.
\end{equation*}

Combining the above results we have that

\begin{equation*}
I=\left( e^{x}x-e^{x}\right) -2e^{x}=e^{x}x-3e^{x}=\left( x-3\right) e^{x}.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want $u$ to be something that doesn't get more complicated when you differentiate it and $dv$ to be something that doesn't get more complicated when you antidifferentiate it.  In
$$
\underbrace{(x-2)}_u\ \ \underbrace{\ e^x\, dx\ }_{dv}\ ,
$$
differentiating $u$ gives $1$, and antidifferentiating $dv$ gives something equally complicated, not more.  Multiplying by $1$ is simple.